# What is the resource interpretation of $A \to B$ in linear logic?

Tags: logic, soft-question, linear-logic

Linear logic seems to have two forms of implication.

$$A \multimap B$$

With resource interpretation of "consuming A yields B".

And the usual

$$A \rightarrow B$$

What is the resource interpretation of regular implication in linear logic?

For example, I've seen $A \rightarrow B$ sometimes re-interpreted as:

$$A! \multimap B$$

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is not a reliable way to translate classical logical formulas to resource-sensitive essence of linear logic just over semantic instructions. Thus, many interpretations are *ex post facto* attempts to make sense of formal results.

Presuming your intention by "regular implication" is "material implication" ($A \rightarrow B$) in classical logic, I think we can reason as follows:

We may think of propositions as place-holders for resources. Material implication tells that either we do not have, and thus, demand a resource *A*, or else, we have got a resource *B* available. In other words, we have either the absence of resource (i.e., to be supplied) A or the presence of resource (to be consumed) B.

Since these are "classical" resources; we can freely restore or dispose of them over and over again on demand. So we have the alternatives

$$!A \multimap !B$$ and

$$?A \multimap ?B$$

We supply either ?A to be consumed some amount and yield proportionately ?B, hence

$$!?A \multimap ?B$$

or we consume !B some amount and need proportionately !A, hence

$$!A \multimap ?!B$$

which are the expressions for material implication in **LL**.

Comment: I thought that $A \implies B$ is equivalent to $A! \multimap B$?